# Why does ansible think this variable is undefined?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following vars in a `all.yml` under `/group_vars/`:

```
---
global__:

  app_user: root
  app_group: root

  maven_repo:  http://my.endpoint.a
  package_repo:  http://my.endpoint.b

  java:
    sourceUrl: "{{package_repo}}/java/"
    version: 1.8.0_25
```

However, when I get to the first task that expands this var file, I get the following output:

```
 FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! ERROR! 'package_repo' is undefined"}
```

Why?

Comment: try quoting the variable value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package_repo` is defined within the `global__` dictionary. Because of that you would need to reference it as `{{ global__.package_repo }}`, but since you are referencing from within the same dictionary, you will get the error `recursive loop detected in template string`. You cannot reference from within the same datastructure, however referencing from another datastructure should work.

So you need to define `package_repo` in another structure in order to reference it inside the `global__.java.sourceUrl` variable, e.g. the following would work:

```
package_repo:  http://my.endpoint.b

global__:

  app_user: root
  app_group: root

  maven_repo:  http://my.endpoint.a

  java:
    sourceUrl: "{{package_repo}}/java/"
    version: 1.8.0_25
```

or

```
other_map:
  package_repo:  http://my.endpoint.b

global__:

  app_user: root
  app_group: root

  maven_repo:  http://my.endpoint.a

  java:
    sourceUrl: "{{other_map.package_repo}}/java/"
    version: 1.8.0_25
```

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate. Defining it outside the `global__` scope isn't really an option, as it breaks the continuity of the scopes set in place. Thanks for the info though!